# I'm trying to copy one month data from one table to other which is huge when they insert it in the table using insert into T2 select * fr

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, compiler-errors

I'm trying to copy one month data from one table to other which is huge when they insert it in the table using code below.
It is showing data too wide to compile .Pl/SQL

```
insert into T2 select * from T1 where date >'Date';
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error you see and give us an idea of how "huge" the table is? How many columns, how many rows

Comment: 51000 rows,SQL Error:ORA-12899:Value too large for column

Comment: So it has nothing to do with number of rows, 51000 generally speaking is nothing.
The problem is that your T2 doesn't exactly match T1, there is some column in T1 that has the same name probably but different max length (in this case bigger than corresponding column from T2). See https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-12899-value-too-large-for-column/#:~:text=The%20ORA%2D12899%20is%20an,wide%20for%20the%20destination%20column.

Comment: Check table definitions, if you will not be able to find the difference - provide table definitions here (CREATE TABLE would do)

Comment: There is a difference in defination for one it has varchar (1) and other it has varchaelr (2) I tried alter table  modify char(1); but it is showing ORA-01441:Cannot decrease column length because some value is too big

Comment: Yes, so that means that some value in that column has 2 symbols. So you should increase the other one instead

Comment: Thankyou  Nikita I'm able to insert after  increasing the char value.